# Created Middleware but it is not working in Laravel 5.5

Tags: php, laravel, authentication, middleware

I want to authenticate view file for particular users. I have created middleware for this. Below is the code for middleware:-

```
namespace App\Http\Middleware;

use Closure;

use Illuminate\Support\Facades\Auth;

class ClientAuth
{
    public function handle($request, Closure $next)
    {
        if(Auth::user() && Auth::user()->account_type==3)
        {
            return $next($request);
        }

            return redirect('/');

    }
}
```

Next, I have called 'client' middleware in kernel.php file. Below is the code:-

```
protected $routeMiddleware = [
    'auth' => \Illuminate\Auth\Middleware\Authenticate::class,
    'auth.basic' => \Illuminate\Auth\Middleware\AuthenticateWithBasicAuth::class,
    'bindings' => \Illuminate\Routing\Middleware\SubstituteBindings::class,
    'can' => \Illuminate\Auth\Middleware\Authorize::class,
    'guest' => \App\Http\Middleware\RedirectIfAuthenticated::class,
    'throttle' => \Illuminate\Routing\Middleware\ThrottleRequests::class,
    'admin' => \App\Http\Middleware\isAdmin::class,
    'client' => \App\Http\Middleware\ClientAuth::class
];
```

Then, i have called this in route.

```
Route::group(['middleware' => ['auth','client']], function () 
{

   Route::get('clientdatabase',
   'ClientDatabase\ClientdatabaseController@ClientDatabase');

});
```

This is not working. Where am i going wrong?

Comment: "not working" isn't a description of what is hapening ... what do you expect to happen and what is actually happening

Comment: you don't need the auth middleware

Comment: If i remove auth middleware, it is not working

Comment: "it is not working" ... do we really have to continue to do this over and over again?

Comment: Okay any other alternative for this?

Comment: Lagbox asked you to provide a proper error message or a description of what "not working" means for you? So answer the questions:
What do you expect to happen? What happens instead of your expectations?

Comment: Oh okay! sorry my mistake. Actually in middleware I have given condition if account_type==3, it should redirect user to the specific url  else to other url. So it was not redirecting. Well, i got the issue, it has been solved. Thanks!

Answer (score -1):

your called is wrong  in route.
for example

```
  Route::middleware(['auth','client'])->group(function () {

       Route::get('clientdatabase','ClientDatabase\ClientdatabaseController@ClientDatabase');

    });
```

Comment: this is just an alternative way to register the group

Comment: Thanks! But still no change.